# Showing an iOS app badge through FirebaseMessaging background messages

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm developing an app in Flutter and have run in to some problems. What I want to happen is

1. Through some event, a push notification is sent to the user using FCM. I send both a `notification` and `data` message so that the `onBackgroundMessage` handler is called.
2. The handler ups the badge count with 1 every time a message is received.

My mesage payloads look like this:

```
const payload = {
    notification: {  
        title: String(data["title"]),
        body: String(data["message"]),
    },
    data: {
        title: data["title"],
        body: data["message"],
    },
}
const payloadBackground = {
    data: {
        title: data["title"],
        body: data["message"],
    },
    content_available: true,
    priority: "high"
}
```

This is run as a Firebase Cloud Function using `FirebaseMessaging`:

```
admin.messaging().sendToDevice(receiverRegistrationTokens, payloadBackground).catch(err => console.error(err));
return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(receiverRegistrationTokens, payload).then( response => {
    console.log(receiver + " has registrationTokens: " + receiverRegistrationTokens);
    return null;
})
```

On the client side, notifications are handled like this:

```
Future<void> backgroundNotificationHandler(RemoteMessage message) {
  FlutterAppBadger.updateBadgeCount(1);
  debugPrint("Received notification: " + message.data.toString());
  return null;
}
```

```
AwesomeNotifications().initialize(
    // set the icon to null if you want to use the default app icon
    'resource://drawable/res_app_icon',
    [
      NotificationChannel(
        channelKey: 'basic_channel',
        channelName: 'Basic notifications',
        channelDescription: 'Notification channel for basic tests',
        defaultColor: Color(0xFF9D50DD),
        ledColor: Colors.white,
        enableLights: true,
      )
    ]);
FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(backgroundNotificationHandler);
```

For some reason, the badge count does not increase (there is no badge at all) on iOS. Push notifications are displayed correctly however. Any ideas on how to tackle this? Much appreciated!

Comment: Do you get the `debugPrint` output in _backgroundNotificationHandler_?

Comment: Nope, I don't, but I suppose that's normal since the handler is only called when the application is in the background or terminated

Comment: Is `onBackgroundMessage` a top level function, outside any classes? Do you try it on iOS emulator real device?

Comment: Yes, it's a top level function, and we have tested it on a real iOS device through TestFlight to make sure all the necessary certificates were included for the push notifications

Comment: On iOS the background notification will arrive only when in background, and not when terminated. I am not sure but try putting `content_available` within `notification`, earlier it was true that you needed an only-data message, but maybe it works with notification in the newer versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried in my environment, and the following `Node.js` Firebase Function callable does trigger background message on real iOS device, and also if I add a `print` to the background message handler, I can see the output in debug console:

```
// send a test message
exports.testMessage = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    try {
        await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(
            '<TOKENS>', {
            data: {
                key1: 'value1',
            },
            notification: {
                title: 'Title1',
                body: 'Body1'
            }
        }, {
            contentAvailable: true,
            priority: "high",
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

`contentAvailable: true` is all that is required to call the background handler. According to the documentation:

> Specifies whether to configure a background update notification.

Comment: Hmm okay thanks for the help, I will try this out later and let you know if it worked! :)

Comment: @JesseGeens I received your edit suggestion. Please check [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message), at the very bottom of page. It says `priority` can be `high`, and message expiration has to be set using `timeToLive` in seconds.

Comment: And [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.MessagingOptions#optional-priority), it says that `priority` as text "normal" or "high" will be transformed to APNs priorities 5 and 10 respectively.